# jquery slides and html5 video

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video, slidesjs

I am trying to use an HTML5 video as the first element in a [SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com/) slideshow. The problem is if I click on the play button to play the video, the slideshow should stop until the video finishes completely and then the slideshow should move to the next slide. Also, the hoverpause works only on images but not on html5 video element.

Here's my JavaScript code so far:

```
$(function () {
    $('#slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        preloadImage: 'Images/loading.gif',
        play: 5000,
        pause: 2500,
        hoverPause: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Media Events](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) has an overview of the exposed events you can tap into.
You should simply stop the slideshow on the `play` event and restart it on the `ended` event.

Example: `<video ... onPlay="//DoJSStuffHere" onEnded="//DoOtherJSStuffHere" />`

Comment: thanks semyazas.that makes sense. but how do you get the current state of the video element?

Comment: There is a `playing` state you could check for, as well as a `pause` but i personally guess it will be enough to stop the slides on a beginning `play` and run it further on a `pause` as those events will HAVE to happen to make the video run or stop. See my updated answer

Comment: Ehm I wouldn't recomend adding on attributes on any elements..guh! Do it completely with javascript.

Comment: That's just a basic example to give him the opportunity to do a quick check. True though, the example is in this case far from ideal

Answer (score 0):

Like Semyazas says, but skip the on-attributes and do it with javascript:

```
var v = document.getElementById("id-of-movie");
//$(v).bind('pause', function () { the video gets paused }
//$(v).bind('play', function () { do something when the video starts playing, fired by v.play()
//$(v).bind('ended', function () { the video has ended }
```

Comment: `var v = $('#id-of-movie'); ` if he's using jQuery anyways ;-)

Comment: Cannot do that, if you do that, you also need to add
$('#id-of-movie').get(0); :)

Comment: It's still far better than switching out of the framework and back in. That way lies syntax-errors

Comment: Btw, that gave me something to think. I can remember successfully not using the `.get(0);` So i just tried it: http://jsfiddle.net/yQFQX/ and as you can see...it works

Comment: That's not making sense. I'm using an id, which has to be unique. So all i'm doing there is **the same as you do** but in jQuery syntax, instead of regular javascript. That is because the id-selector uses `document.getElementById('#idgoeshere')`, so if you had to add get(0), it would be the same for your code.

Comment: document.getElementById('#idgoeshere') is not the same as $('#idgoeshere')

Comment: @tbleckert let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2057/discussion-between-semyazas-and-tbleckert)

Comment: $() returns a jQuery object - doesn't work with video events
document.getElementById() returns a HTML Dom Object - works with video events

Comment: initially i thought of doing it with getelementbyid but not sure whether it will work html5video.